# Why does $\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1}\binom{i-1}{n-1}2^{1-i}$ computes the probability of $n$ head or tails

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

$\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1}\binom{i-1}{n-1}2^{1-i}$

For $i = n,n+1,\ldots, 2n - 1$, the sum above computes $P(E_i)$, the probability that i
tosses of a fair coin are required before obtaining $n$ heads or $n$ tails.

I am not asking for a solution. I am confused by how that summation computes the probability described in the hint. Shouldn't the binomial coefficient be $\binom{i}{n}$? That's the only question I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earliest that you can get $n$ heads or $n$ tails is the $n$-th toss, and the latest is the $(2n-1)$-st toss. How many ways are there to get it on the $i$-th toss, where $n\le i\le 2n-1$? Let’s say that you get the $n$-th tail on the $i$-th toss. That means that you must have got $n-1$ tails in the first $i-1$ tosses, and they could any $n-1$ of those tosses. Thus, there are $\binom{i-1}{n-1}$ strings of heads and tails that would allow you to get the $n$-th tail on the $i$-th toss. The probability of getting any one of those strings is $2^{-(i-1)}=2^{1-i}$. The probability of getting a tail on the $i$-th toss is $\frac12$, so the probability of a string of length $i$ that has exactly $n$ tails and ends with a tail is $\frac12\cdot\binom{i-1}{n-1}2^{1-i}$. The probability of getting the $n$-th head on the $i$-th toss is identical, so the probability of getting one or the other of these outcomes is

$$2\cdot\frac12\binom{i-1}{n-1}2^{1-i}=\binom{i-1}{n-1}2^{1-i}\;.$$

Comment: Isn't the latest the $2n$- toss?

Comment: @crystal_math: No: if you have at most $n-1$ heads and at most $n-1$ tails, you’ve tossed at most $2n-2$ times, and the $(2n-1)$-st toss is guaranteed to get you either the $n$-th head or the $n$-th tail.

Comment: Additionally, could you point out the flaw in this interpretation? The probability of getting a $i$ long string with $n$ tails is $2^{-i}$. The number of ways that can happen is $\binom{i}{n}$. Hence we get the expression $2^{-i}\binom{i}{n}$. Since we can argue in the exact same way for heads, we double this value and get $2^{1-i}\binom{i}{n}$. This was how I was seeing it. I am convinced that your response is correct but I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I meant to say $2n-1$. I think you wrote $2n+1$ accidentally.

Comment: @crystal_math: Thanks for catching the typo; yes, that was supposed to be $(2n-1)$st. There are $\binom{i}n$ strings of length $i$ that contain exactly $n$ tails, but only $\binom{i-1}{n-1}$ of them end with a tail. If the $i$-th toss is a head, then we actually got $n$ tails **before** the $i$-th toss.

Comment: Ahh. Thank you! I should have read the statement carefully!

Comment: @crystal_math: You’re welcome!